# Autocomplete function in search bar using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

every one. I am trying to make a autocomplete search buts its not working.
when a user write in search bar, data comes through the a column from a table.
here is the code:
View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>


</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>
$( "#country_id" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/new/index.php/travels/search_fields",
            data: { term: $("#country_id").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
               var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                    return obj.tag;
               }); 

               response(resp);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2
});
</script>

<form>
<input type="text" name="country_id" id="country_id" >                   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Model:

```
public function search_field($country_id){
$q= $this->db->query("select()->from('travels_detail')->where('destination', $country_id");
        echo json_encode($q->result_array());

    }
```

Controller:

```
public function search_fields(){
        $destination= $this->input->post('country_id');
        $this->travel->search_field($country_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In model your active query was wrong `$this->db->query("select()->from('travels_detail')->where('destination', $country_id");`, and your are missed `->get()` in active query.

Follow bellow like this :

```
public function search_field($country_id){
    $q = $this->db->select("*")->from('travels_detail')->where('destination', $country_id)->get();
    echo json_encode($q->result_array());
}
```

or,

```
public function search_field($country_id){
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('travels_detail');
    $this->db->where('destination', $country_id);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    echo json_encode($q->result_array());
}
```

In controller instead `$destination` to `$country_id`

You calling in ajax `term` POST value like this `data: { term: $("#country_id").val()},` but you calling in controller `$this->input->post('country_id');`

so, in controller `$country_id = $this->input->post('term');`

So, your controller is :

```
public function search_fields(){
    $country_id = $this->input->post('term');
    $this->travel->search_field($country_id);
}
```

Comment: yeah i changed the model but it showing empty array

Comment: I have edited my answer. In controller instead `$destination` to `$country_id`

Comment: changed the controller code and change the ajax code:

Comment: $.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost/new/index.php/travels/search_fields',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { term: $("#country_id").val()},
   success:function(data){
    $('#country_list_id').show();
    $('#country_list_id').html(data);
   }
  });

Comment: what is situation now?

Comment: an empty array display, like that  []

Comment: public function search_fields(){
    $country_id = $this->input->post('term');
    $this->travel->search_field($country_id);
}

Comment: what are you getting `$country_id` this variable? and what is data in `destination` field in db table? are you sure this both same content?

Comment: i am getiing the input value in country_id ... it is the id of input and destination is the name of the column in a table

Comment: put `$this->db->last_query();` before `echo json_encode($q->result_array());` this line in your model. and run this query in your phpmyamin. and let me know.

Comment: no its not working and the query is ok. i think there is problem in ajax. could u rewrite ajax for me ... Thanx